# Angular material autocomplete scrolling issue

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

In my application, the overflow is put on  tag instead of  tag. Using autocomplete, the panel does not stick to its field

[image]

I am trying to find a way to tell autocomplete component to follow another scroll than the body one. Any idea ?

I tried with cdkScrollable directive

Comment: Can you please post code on the stackblitz and share the url?

Comment: Here you are: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pvmarv, if you open the panel, then you scroll, the panel won't stick to the field